# Invalid Token JWT Auth

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4, jwt

I am using jwt auth for the token work in laravel. Its working fine on rest client but when I call it in web service, out of 10 times, 2 times it returns invalid_token error. When ever internet speed is fast, it starts returning invalid_token, on 2G, it is working fine. Can any one please let me know the solution?

Is their some timing issue?

Comment: please add source code

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 or 5? Tagging both doesn't help, plus post your code

Comment: Laravel 4 is the version @Ian